# python equivalent of functools 'partial' for a class / constructor

Tags: python, partial, functools

I want to create a class that behaves like collections.defaultdict, without having the usage code specify the factory. EG:
instead of

```
class Config(collections.defaultdict):
    pass
```

this:

```
Config = functools.partial(collections.defaultdict, list)
```

This almost works, but

```
isinstance(Config(), Config)
```

fails. I am betting this clue means there are more devious problems deeper in also. So is there a way to actually achieve this?

I also tried:

```
class Config(Object):
    __init__ = functools.partial(collections.defaultdict, list)
```

Comment: Wouldn't a more reasonable check be: `isinstance(Config(), collections.defaultdict)`? As long as `Config` is not a class, `isinstance` will of course fail. As explicit type checks aren't common / recommended in python you might as well keep using `Config` as above - it should work as intented in many cases.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard method to do it, but if you need it often, you can just put together your own small function:

```
import functools
import collections


def partialclass(cls, *args, **kwds):

    class NewCls(cls):
        __init__ = functools.partialmethod(cls.__init__, *args, **kwds)

    return NewCls


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Config = partialclass(collections.defaultdict, list)
    assert isinstance(Config(), Config)
```

Comment: FYI: I submitted this code to Python https://bugs.python.org/issue33419

Comment: Drats - I was hoping to see this implemented, rather than deferred (probably forever) and closed!

Comment: Is there a way to make `Config.__repr__` display something more reasonable besides `partialclass.<locals>.NewCls`? I think this would be similar to `functools.wraps` but the only way to know what the new class is called is from its declaration

Answer (score 23):

At least in Python 3.8.5 it just works with `functools.partial`:

```py
import functools

class Test:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
    
PartialClass = functools.partial(Test, 1)

instance = PartialClass()
instance.foo
```

Comment: Bear in mind that you can't subclass this or nest the partial call. Which I needed.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem but also required instances of my partially applied class to be pickle-able. I thought I would share what I ended up with.

I adapted fjarri's answer by peeking at Python's own `collections.namedtuple`. The below function creates a named subclass that can be pickled.

```py
from functools import partialmethod
import sys

def partialclass(name, cls, *args, **kwds):
    new_cls = type(name, (cls,), {
        '__init__': partialmethod(cls.__init__, *args, **kwds)
    })

    # The following is copied nearly ad verbatim from `namedtuple's` source.
    """
    # For pickling to work, the __module__ variable needs to be set to the frame
    # where the named tuple is created.  Bypass this step in enviroments where
    # sys._getframe is not defined (Jython for example) or sys._getframe is not
    # defined for arguments greater than 0 (IronPython).
    """
    try:
        new_cls.__module__ = sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        pass

    return new_cls
```

Answer (score 10):

If you actually need working explicit type checks via `isinstance`, you can simply create a not too trivial subclass:

```
class Config(collections.defaultdict):

    def __init__(self): # no arguments here
        # call the defaultdict init with the list factory
        super(Config, self).__init__(list)
```

You'll have no-argument construction with the list factory and

```
isinstance(Config(), Config)
```

will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Could use `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def printy(self):
        print("a:", self.a, ", b:", self.b)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(*args, b=123, **kwargs)

if __name__=="__main__":
    bar = Bar(1)
    bar.printy()  # Prints: "a: 1 , b: 123"
```