# How to create an object of a certain class by dynamically passing only one (perhaps multiple but not all) parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Let's say I have the following class.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

obj_A = A(y=2) # Dynamically pass the parameters
```

My question is, how can I dynamically create an object of a certain class by passing only one (perhaps multiple but not all) parameters? Also, I have prior knowledge of the attributes name i.e. **'x'** and **'y'** and they all have a default value.

Edit: To clear up some confusion. The class can have any number of attributes. Is it possible to create an instance by passing any subset of the parameters during runtime?

I know I can use `getters` and `setters` to achieve this, but I'm working on OpenCV python, and these functions are not implemented for some algorithms.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are looking for. In your code, `obj_A` is an instance of class `A`. With `y` as `2` and `x` set to `0`.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Is it **kwarg you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911146/python-equivalent-of-functools-partial-for-a-class-constructor)

**Code**

```
import functools

class A:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
      return f'x:{self.x}, y:{self.y}'  # added to see instance data

def partialclass(cls, *args, **kwds):

    class NewCls(cls):
        __init__ = functools.partialmethod(cls.__init__, *args, **kwds)

    return NewCls
```

**Test**

```
# Create Partial Class (setting x only)
A_init = partialclass(A, x=3.14159)

# Setting y dynamically
# Create instance from A_init by setting y
a_2 = A_init(y=2)
print(a_2)  # Out: x:3.14159, y:2

# Create instance from A_init using y default
a_default = A_init()   
print(a_default)       # Out: x:3.14159, y:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are looking for dynamic class creation. If so, you should use `type(name,bases,dict)`.

check this
[previous strackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555844/dynamically-creating-a-class-from-file-in-python)